# Dimension of a set detected by a homology class

Tags: smooth-manifolds

A colleague asked me a topology question which comes down to this: Suppose that $M$ is a smooth $n$-manifold, and $C\subset M$ is a closed set such that $H_{n-p}(M-C)\to H_{n-p}(M)$ is not surjective. What can you say about $C$? Clearly in some sense it is at least $p$-dimensional, but in what sense? For example, must it have a subset homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^p$?

Comment: That's what the topological duality theorems are about.

Comment: What are the topological duality theorems?

Comment: First there was the absolute (just for the spaces, not for subsets) Poincare duality theorem. Then there was Alexander-Pontryagin theorem for subsets of a manifold. On the later occasion Pontryagin introduced his duality theorem for topological groups--initially it was about compact abelian groups versus discrete abelian groups. (This was generalized to locallyt compact abelian groups  Egbert van Kampen in 1935 and André Weil in 1940--see wikipedia). An early result about dissecting $\mathbb R^n$ by a compact subset was obtained by Karol Borsuk. Etc. (you need to ask not me but a specialist).

Comment: Certainly some kind of $p$th Cech cohomology of $C$ is nontrivial. My question is, what does this imply geometrically about $C$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For sure you can not expect a subset homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^p$.

Say, take $p=1$ and $M=\mathbb T^2$. 
Note that there is an open embedding of cylinder $f\colon (0,1)\times \mathbb S^1\to\mathbb T^2$
such that the complement $\Sigma=\mathbb T^2 \backslash \mathrm{Im}f$ is a [pseudo-circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoarc).
In particular $\Sigma$ does not contain a subset homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.
Clearly 
$$\mathbb Z=H_{1}(\mathbb T^2-\Sigma)\to H_{1}(\mathbb T^2)=\mathbb Z^2$$
is not surjective.

P.S. The pseudo-circle can be constructed as an intersection of nested *crooked* chains of dics. Here is the image of a chain crooked in a circular chain with 6 links [from here](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~pyrih/e/e2001v1/c/ect/node99.html); it gives the second iteration in the construction.

[image]

Comment: Why is the complement homeomorphic to a cylinder?

Comment: Thank you, Anton. I did not know that there were such strange examples in such low dimensions.

Comment: Anton, what do you mean by statement: *For sure you can not expect a subset homeomorphic to* $\mathbb R^p$ ?

Comment: Anton, your link says "*pseudo-circle*", while it points to wikipedia article on *pseudo-arc*, and it does not mention pseudo-circle at all. Could you comment about it?

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski: search the web on "pseudo-circle" and "continuum".

Comment: I gather, Cech cohomology of the pseudo-circle are the same as for the circle, so by Alexander duality its complement in the plane has two components and has first homology isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. By the classification of surfaces this means that the complement's components are open disk and open annulus. Joining them by a handle gives the desired embedding into the $2$-torus. The only thing I am not sure about is whether the first Cech cohomology is $\mathbb Z$, but if this weren't true, why would it be called pseudo-circle?

Comment: @Igor Belegradek (quote: *search the web on "pseudo-circle" and "continuum"*)--no need to. But thank you for your effort.

Comment: This is a nice picture but I'd rather see an explanation why the pseudo-circle has a) infinite cyclic first Cech cohomology and b) no manifold point.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, I think all this standard, isn't it? I only wanted to indicate the construction.

Comment: I could not even find where a)-b) are stated (let alone proved). Appparently, pseudo-circle is not homogeneous, so homogeneity cannot be used to show b).

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, All this follows directly from the construction.